# Python hangs on consecutive power calculation

Tags: python, math

Python  2.7.13 interpreter hangs on  calculating

1 ** 2 ** 3 ** 4 ** 5

But why?

Comment: Because that's a *reeeeeeeeally* big number that takes a long time to compute?

Comment: `3**4**5` is `373391848741020043532959754184866588225409776783734007750636931722079040617265251229993688938803977220468765065431475158108727054592160858581351336982809187314191748594262580938807019951956404285571818041046681288797402925517668012340617298396574731619152386723046235125934896058590588284654793540505936202376547807442730582144527058988756251452817793413352141920744623027518729185432862375737063985485319476416926263819972887006907013899256524297198527698749274196276811060702333710356481`. What were you expecting `2` raised to that power to give?

Comment: Also python's not intelligent enough to look at the 1 and know the answer's 1

Comment: python calculates this as : `1**(2**(3**(4**5)))`

Comment: Before downvoting, consider the OP has a 1 on the left. It is not an unfair question to ask.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh what do you mean?

Comment: Just pointing out that essentially "powers are right associative" might be something the OP wasnt aware of. (I know i wasnt till now)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Agree, people aren't born with a precedence & associativity table in their head and `(((1**2)**3)**4)**5` is the intuitive way of reading this if you're familiar with division.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte that's a math misunderstanding then not python. [explanation from wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Direction_of_evaluation) "This order is important because exponentiation is not associative"

Comment: Well exponentiation is associative in python, so it has nothing to do with math :o)

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. The answer to both questions may be the same but for different reasons. This question is actually eye-catchingly interesting: `1**N == 1` for all N so why does an expression which eventually evaluates to 1 cause python to hang? Whether you evaluate right-to-left `1**(2**(3**(4**5)))`  or left-to-right `(((1**2)**3)**4)**5` the answer is 1 in both cases. Of course it's the very large intermediate ( see Mark Dicksons) in the default non-parenthesized right-to-left evaluation that presumably causes an intermediate overflow. Nice question alpintrekker.

Comment: @glibdud: I computed it in my head in an instant :)

Comment: @JamesKPolk Well, to be fair, you're allowed to work left-to-right. :P

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is your understanding of exponentiation associativity:

```
>>> 2**3**4
2417851639229258349412352
>>> 2**(3**4)
2417851639229258349412352
>>> (2**3)**4
4096
```

You need to reed from right to left unlike division associativity.

```
>>> 2/3/4
0.16666666666666666
>>> 2/(3/4)
2.6666666666666665
>>> (2/3)/4
0.16666666666666666
```